# npm run client & npm run server not running properly (won't run at the same time)

Tags: node.js, json, npm, node-modules

In the image you can see the scripts I am using, and on the left side is the folders hierarchy.

According to the defined script when I am running `npm run watch`, it should run `server` script and `client` script as well. But it's only running one script `server`. It never actually runs the `client` script.

Same thing happens if I put it like `npm run client & npm run server` in `watch` script. It runs only `client` script and never reaches `server` script.

One more: If I run `npm install` it doesn't install as defined in the script. Throws error `EISDIR` (error shown in image).

Please explain why is this happening and how I can fix this.

Thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: when you use --prefix flag, if the input is a directory prepend ./  . In your case it should be npm install --prefix ./server. The error is EISDIR, meaning Error, Is Directory?
Try running server and client in different terminals.

Comment: Yeah, I can run in different terminals, but I wanted to do it in a single terminal.

Comment: What about the first issue? Can you tell me why doesn't `client` script not run and only `server` script runs when I run npm `watch` script?

Comment: I know it's too many comments, your definition of error is correct, but your solution/fix for the problem doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

there is a npm package called concurrently, you can install it as dev dependency and use it to run your watch script.

first install concurrently: "npm isntall concurrently --save"

then on your script:  "watch": "concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""

you can now run both server and client from one script.

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try running this script:

```
"watch":"npm-run-all --parallel server client"
```